# Cloudwatch metrics for multiple dimensions

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following data-
{
userNames
failureMessage
}
I want to populate metric for this such that every user is able to do see what are the failureMessages for them. Now there are more than 100 users right now. I thought we can have dimensionList with userName and failureMessage in it. However, dimensions have a hard limit of 25. Is there any other way I can solve this using cloudwatch metrics?

Usecase: Our executions run  ~1000 times every day and they are bound to fail most of the times. However, a user wants to understand the failures and minimize them. The data in cloudwatch I have is something like this:

2023-08-15T15:11:40.797-07:00

```
(-some-unique-id) Endpoint request body after transformations: {"userName": "testUser", "failureReason":"We failed"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The usage you're describing doesn't sound at all like the supported usage of CloudWatch. CloudWatch is meant for analyzing long term trends of your metrics or alarming.

Including failure message as a dimension in CloudWatch would result in sparse metrics (i.e. metrics that only have one or very few data points). Each individual value for a dimension would result in a brand new metric being emitted into CloudWatch and you will be charged for it. As such, this might result in very high bills.

I would recommend using a mixture of CloudWatch Metrics, Contributor Insights, and Logs. Let me explain!

- Emit one single metric for the failures. You might consider including a dimension for the "kind" of failure (e.g. "timeout", "bad request", etc.) - this can be used for analyzing long-term trends of the failure KPI, as well as alarms.
- Emit logs into CloudWatch Logs with the failure message for your user - as a good practice, make sure you don't include customer indentifying information in your logs.
- Configure a Contributor Insights rule to count the failures per user based on your logs - this will allow you to report the amount of failures per user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my use-case in the question. Hope that makes it clearer. Wondering how do I configure a contributor insight rule with the example log I shared above?

Comment: Apologies, but I couldn't write any specifics now as I'm not in front of a computer. I advise reading through the Contributor Insights documentation as that will surely have some guidance :)